ExposedDropdownMenuBox requires two tabs to gain/change focus
I'm trying to get keyboard navigation working nicely in my desktop multiplatform app so when you press tab it moves to the next input field.
It works when it's a regular TextField, but I have a mix of text and ExposedDropdownMenuBox fields.
It always takes two tabs to get the ExposedDropdownMenuBox properly focused.
From a TextField, a tab into the ExposedDropdownMenuBox removes focus from the TextField.  The next tab focuses the ExposedDropdownMenuBox and the menu appears.
You can then press tab to move between the selections and press enter to select what you want, which closes the ExposedDropdownMenuBox.
From there, pressing tab again unfocuses the ExposedDropdownMenuBox, without focusing the next one.  The next tab focuses the next box correctly.
I've tried the focusable/onFocusEvent on the ExposedDropdownMenuBox and TextField below but it makes no difference.
I can't figure out how to prevent this extra tab?
Here's what I'm using
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun <Value> OutlinedDropDown(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isEnabled: Boolean,
    label: String,
    displayValue: String,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    textFieldColors: TextFieldColors,
    onClick: (Value) -> Unit,
    dropDownContent: () -> List<Pair<String, Value>>
) {
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp).focusable()
            .onFocusEvent {
                if (it.hasFocus) {
                    isExpanded = true
                }
            },
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onExpandedChange = { isExpanded = !isExpanded },
    ) {
        TextField(
            isError = isError,
            enabled = isEnabled,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .menuAnchor(MenuAnchorType.PrimaryEditable, true),
            readOnly = true,
            value = displayValue,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = if (label.isBlank()) null else {
                { Text(label) }
            },
            colors = textFieldColors,
            singleLine = true
        )
        if (isEnabled) {
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = isExpanded,
                onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false }
            ) {
                dropDownContent.invoke().forEach { displayAndValue ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        enabled = isEnabled,
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                displayAndValue.first,
                                maxLines = 1
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            onClick.invoke(displayAndValue.second)
                            isExpanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And it's just a row of these...
Row() {
    OutlinedDropDown(
        ..
        modifier = Modifier.weight(0.40f).padding(2.dp),
        ..
     ) {
        ..
     }

    OutlinedDropDown(
        ..
        modifier = Modifier.weight(0.30f).padding(2.dp),
        ..
     ) {
        ..
     }
     OutlinedDropDown(
        ..
        modifier = Modifier.weight(0.30f).padding(2.dp),
        ..
     ) {
        ..
     }
}

